# What are these things on the paw?

Tags: cats, health

Could you tell me what these on my cat's paw are and what was the cause? It looks like dried blood, but I don't think this is what it really is. As you can see, there's no hair on this place as the cat bit it off.

It is only on this thumb of this paw. I can't tell how it looked like before, because he wouldn't let me. There's no other symptoms.

[image]

Comment: Is this just on the one paw? What did it look like before the cat bit it off?

Comment: Yes, it is only on this thumb of this paw. I can't tell how it looked like before, because he wouldn't let me.

Comment: looks like a scab from a insect bite or scratch. Any other symptoms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a veterinarian

It's hard to answer these things definitively, particularly online.

Given there's no other symptoms and it's isolated to the one place, it appears to be a scab your cat had scratched (or bitten) off. The scab could have formed from an insect bite, scratch or cut from a thorn or various other sharp things in the environment.

Scabbing is always a good indicator that the wound is not fresh. So if there's no pus, inflammation or other signs of infection or toxicity, the cat should be fine, as these types of symptoms generally show up over the first few days.

If ever in doubt, take you pet to a qualified veterinarian, as they can offer immediate expertise and care that we cannot online.